# Why doesn't enum require an object creation in this example?

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2015, enums, instantiation

I have a library.

```
namespace Defintnions
{
    public class skywave
    {
        public enum partnum : byte { assembled, configured };
        public readonly string partnum_assembled = "1234B";
    }
}
```

I am testing it in this other project in the same solution.

```
using Defintnions;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class MainEntry
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string test3 = skywave.partnum.Assembled.ToString(); //assembled

            string zxcv = skywave.partnumAssembled; //doesnt compile
            skywave obj = new skywave();               
            string asdf = obj.partnumAssembled;       //1234B

            Console.WriteLine(test3);
            Console.WriteLine(asdf);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I am confused why `test3` doesn't require creation of the `enum` object locally.

I think its very clean though, which leads me to wonder if there is a way to do something similar, but instead have the output of the `enum` be an alphanumeric.

Ideally I would want my library to have the ability to do the following, but without the hassle of creating an object first.

```
string zxcv = skywave.partnum.assembled; //1234B
```

Comment: You're defining an `enum` type in your class, not a field whose type is an `enum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enums are types in C#.  In your code, `skywave` is a class that contains an enum called `partwave`.  If you want to be able to reference `partwave` without reference to `skywave`, you need to define it outside of the class:

```
public enum partnum : byte { assembled, configured };
public class skywave
{
    public readonly string partnum_assembled = "1234B";
}
```

If you want to be able to refer to `partnum_assembled` without instantiating `skywave`, you need to define it as `static` or `const`

```
public class skywave
{
    public static readonly string partnum_assembled = "1234B";
}
```

or

```
public class skywave
{
    public const string partnum_assembled = "1234B";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A nested type (in this case an enum, although it would apply to any other variety of nested type) isn't accessed through an *instance* of the containing object, but rather through the containing object itself.

A particular instance of `skywave` doesn't contain *the `partnum` type*.  The whole `skywave` class contains the type, so you access the `enum` through that type.

There is no implicit conversion from an `enum` to `string`, nor is there any way for you to create one.  You would need to create your own custom type, emulating an Enum pattern, to have an implicit conversion to `string`.